# FCM not received if App is killed? Even not showing in system tray

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM not received if App is killed? Even not showing in system tray. Working fine in foreground/background state. I have used the below payload.

```
    {
  "to":"dV_9vNhqkXE:....",
  "notification": {
          "title":"1",
          "body"  : "11",
           "icon"  : "ic_about"
      },
    "data": {
          "type":"11",
          "month":"3333",
          "title":"2222"
      }

}
```

Comment: Try to look around for similar posts like the one ai flagged. This question is common here in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://possiblemobile.com/2014/06/effects-android-application-termination/) link will help you understand more about the state of activities in their foreground and background. It basically says that you wont receive any notification if you have force closed your app, because **"When the app is closed forcelly by the user : notifications don't arrive"**. So, did you force close the app ?

Comment: Yes. I have force closed the App.

Comment: So you wont get notifications when you force close the app and the worst part is that I dont think that it even adds in the queue to be delivered later ! It might get lost completely and you will receive notifications only after you open the app at least once ! But you will lose the notifications when the app was shutdown by force close cause it completely stops all the threads in the app !

Comment: For FCM, it seems to be possible to receive messages even if the app is killed, since the service for receivinf messages is tied to the Google Play Services process.