# How can I receive notifications everytime?

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an application with cordova and I am using a firebase plugin to receive push notification. My problem is: when I kill my app from multitasking I stop receiving. How can I receive these notifications every time?

My device is Huawei P9 with Marshmallow (Emui 4.1.1)

Comment: Force closing an app will kill its services, which prevents it from receiving notifications. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40753765/fcm-not-received-if-app-is-killed-even-not-showing-in-system-tray

Comment: But when I force close WhatsApp I still receive notifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Huawei** devices have a '*protected apps*' settings option... This option **kill the apps** and **app services** when the **screen is off**, what happens? This one kills our fcm service when screen turns off. Actually not existing a programmatically code to solve this, the best option is show a dialog to advice user as can solve this the user just needs let app as protected.

You can find more info in this [post](http://itechify.com/2016/02/01/how-to-fix-missing-push-notifications-on-huawei-smartphones/). Let me know if I have helped you and good programming!

Comment: for wearable connection you have to enable all of the applications: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41622804/1979882